# Is ddrescue/dd cloning compatible with GPT/UEFI boot?

Tags: uefi, dd, gpt, ddrescue, clonezilla

I used **ddrescue** many times for failing HDDs with MBR partition tables. It always worked perfectly and if the failing HDD was bootable, the clone booted, too.

Now I have a possibly failing SSD, but this time it is **GPT** / **UEFI** bootable.
Will ddrescue work for me? Will the clone work and boot correctly?
Couldn't find anything about GPT/UEFI compatibility in the docs.

If not, what alternative(s) do I have?
As far as I know, clonezilla is GPT/UEFI compatible, but I'm not sure if it will work for a failing drive.

Comment: Yes, a cloned copy works also with GPT and/or UEFI. Please remember to connect only one identical drive when booting (so either the original drive or the cloned drive, but not both). Clonezilla works too, and I prefer it, except when ddrescue is necessary to recover sectors that are difficult to read.